# Spinnaker's weird behavior in creating resource conditionally

Tags: spinnaker

I have {{- if .Values.canary.enable }} option on my second kubernetes deployment resource. Deploying the chart with canary.enable: false doesn’t create deployment-v2 at all (which I have expected).
However, deploying with Spinnaker creates deployment-v2, although I have set canary.enable: false on override values.
Why is this kind of weird thing happening ?..